# PHP - How to make url open in new window instead of self (where to enter code?)

Tags: php, url

I'm confused. I need to figure out how to make a link open up in a new tab target="_blank" instead of opening on the same tab target="_self". I'm new to PHP so I am unsure of where the code would be placed.

All of the PHP code I have is in the file below

Lines 55 and 136 are the only lines I've touched for the venue

https://gist.github.com/alexisalexis4/016f617889af00eeb76695075f6cfc76

When I click the Venue Link right now it opens the link on _self

Comment: PHP cannot affect clients browser. If you need to open some link in new tab, here comes `target="blank"`. Or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the job php do. You can change your anchor "" tag "target" attribute to "_blank" then it will do the job for you. Example like below :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Visit Google</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with PHP, it is HTML's anchor tag's attribute - `target="_blank"` which you need to add in your html anchor tags.

**line 102:**

```
$live_button = '<a id="a_register_link-'.$post->ID.'" href="'.$registration_url.'">'.$button_text.'</a>';
```

**line 105:**

```
$live_button = '<a id="a_register_link-'.$post->ID.'" class="a_register_link_sold_out" href="'.$registration_url.'">'.$sold_out_button_text.'</a>';
```

**and line 125:**

```
<td class="td-group reg-col" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $live_button; ?></td>
```

You need to add attribute `target="_blank"` at line 102 and 105. I have **not** shown you how to add it. Can you add it by yourself?